# react-navigation : how to hidden the line which on the TabBar top

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

I'm a React-Native tyro,
when I try to customed the Tab-Navigation ,
I found this line that I couldn't hidden it(that white line!).

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMJx8.png)

I tried to set `borderColor:'00000000'`,but it didn't work
Please help me.

===============================================================================

this is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Home from '../screens/Home';
import Me from '../screens/Me';
import { View, Image, Text } from 'react-native';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconSrc;
          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconSrc = require('../assets/img/影院.png');
          } else if (route.name === 'Me') {
            iconSrc = require('../assets/img/我的.png');
          }

          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return (
            <Image
              source={iconSrc}
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={{
                width: 25,
                height: 25,
                tintColor: focused ? '#FFCF64' : '#6D6D72'
              }}
            />
          );
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#FFCF64',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#6D6D72',
        tabBarStyle: {
          position: 'absolute',
          borderRadius: 25,
          height: 65,
          borderColor: '#333',
          backgroundColor: '#1a1a1a',
          bottom: 30,
          left: 10,
          right: 10
        },
        tabBarItemStyle: {
          height: 65
        }
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarShowLabel: false
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Me"
        component={Me}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarShowLabel: false
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry,I'm fixed it up.
add this code in `tabBarStyle`:`'#00000000'`